# Regex: C# extract value from javascript section

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to extract the value from javascript section found in long html, using typical c# Regex.
Can someone advise what would be the actual pattern to retrieve the '111111111' value?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
document.getElementById( 'interesting' ).value = '11111111111111';
var data= new Object();
etc...
//]]>
</script>
```

C# snippet to parse the above section

```
var pattern = @"get the value";    
private string ExtractJs(string pattern)
{
    return Regex.Match(Html, pattern ).Groups[1].Value;
}
```

Comment: Just make sure to escape the periods and parenthesis like `\.`, `\(`, and `\)`  respectively and the regex should practically write itself.

Comment: You need to be more specific about what constitutes what you want to match.  A pattern like `"111111111"` will satisfy the question you asked.  Are you looking for a string of numbers between single quotes, a string of anything between single quotes being assigned to `.value` of something, or do you need to parse the entire line?

Comment: I am sorry i thought it is clear, I need to get value within  the single quotes. The 111 is just an example and can be anything. My understanding i need to parse whole line and starting with `document.getElementById( 'interesting' ).value` and then get anything after =

Comment: So, did my answer work for you? The only way the next person looking for a solution to a problem like yours would know if my answer is any good is if you *Accept* it or *Up Vote* it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  It results in two `named groups`, one named `key` and the other `value`:

```
document.getElementById\(\s*'(?<key>[^']+)'\s*\)\s*\.\s*value\s*=\s*'(?<value>[^']+)'
```

Explanation:

- Everything up to the first backslash is just a literal.
- The many instances of `\s*` represent optional whitespace of any length
- There are other various literals (single quotes, and `=`, the `\)` and `\(`
- The constructs like this `(?<key>[^']+)` establish "named groups", in this case, the group is named `key`, and it consists of any characters (other than a single quote) between single quotes.

You can fish out the results by calling Matches, taking the first Match and then fishing the results using the named groups syntax.

Full source ends up looking like:

```
 var jsPattern = @"document.getElementById\(\s*'(?<key>[^']+)'\s*\)\s*\.\s*value\s*=\s*'(?<value>[^']+)'";
 var jsRegex = new Regex(jsPattern);

 var sourceCode = "document.getElementById( 'interesting' ).value = '11111111111111';";
 var matches = jsRegex.Matches(sourceCode);
 if (matches.Count == 1)
 {
     var match = matches[0];
     var key = match.Groups["key"];
     var val = match.Groups["value"];
 }
```